# Why i must to include my own lib archive when i´m compiling

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, linker

I have a problem including my own library.

I have created some functions in a few archives `.c`,
after that i have created the header file `.h`,
but when i try to compile a `main.c` that call a function that was in my own lib
i must to type `gcc ownlib.a main.c -o prog.out` and include the lib `ownlib.a` archive
as a parameter of gcc.

In this case i was trying to call my own `strlen()` called `ft_strlen()` function that is in my own lib.

I know when i compile any program using a function that is in a compiler library i only must
include the header in the code for example: `#include <string.h>`,
but when i call my own function i add `#include "ownlib.h"`.

If i compile the `main.c` calling system function `strlen()` i have to compile only the `main.c`
archive and it works.
When i create a lib with my own `ft_strlen()` and in the `main.c` i include my own lib
`#include "ownlib.h"` it doesn´t work if i do this `gcc main.c -o program.out`
but it works if i add my lib archive like this `gcc main.c ownlib.a -o program.out`

I want to know why when i use a system library function i don´t need to compile with the library archive,
for example `gcc main.c string.c -o program.out`,
only whith the `#include <string.h>` it works,
and why i must to include my `ownlib.a` in the compiation `gcc libft.a main.c -o program.out`.
I don't know if I explained myself well

```
LIBNAME = ownlib.a

HEADERNAME = ownlib.h

SRCS = ft_strlen.c

OBJS        = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

CC      = gcc

CFLAGS      = -Wall -Wextra -Werror

AR      = ar

ARFLAGS     = -rcs

$(LIBNAME): $(OBJS) $(HEADERNAME)
    @$(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $(LIBNAME) $(OBJS)

all: $(LIBNAME)

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJS)

fclean: clean
    $(RM) $(LIBNAME)

re: fclean all

%.o: %.c $(HEADERNAME)
    @${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c $< -o ${<:.c=.o}
   

.PHONY: all clean fclean re
```

one of the functions is like this:

```
    
    #include "ownlib.h"

    size_t  ft_strlen(const char *str)
    {
        int     i;

        i = 0;
        while (str[i] != '\0')
                i++;
        return (i);
    }
```

Th main function is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ownlib.h"


int     main(void)
{
        char    *str;
        
        str = "How many characters";
        
        printf("%i", ft_strlen(str);

        return (0);
}
```

If i compile `gcc main.c -o program.out` don´t know what is `ft_strlen()`

Thanks so much

Comment: "*using a function that is in a compiler library i only must include the header*". That's because the linker is configured to automatically link in the standard lib. For your own libs you need to explicitly link them, exactly as you have found.

Comment: Thaks a lot, is there any way for non explicit linking when compiling whith own libs?

Comment: Don't think so. The compiler can't read our minds. One way or another we need to tell it exactly what to link. Some compilers allow directives in the code to tell it what libs are needed for particular source code. But even that is explicit linking just specified in a different way. Why would you even need/want to do that?

Comment: I´m including in the main the directive `#include "ownlib.h` to link my lib, why i must to say to the preprocesor that my `archive.a` is this?

Comment: Well, how would it know that `ownlib.h` is associated with `archive.a`?

Comment: That is what i want to know... how it know that `string.h` is associated with `string.c` or maybe `string.lib`... with Makefile dependendies? That is waht i want to know. Why for `String.c` i only have to say `#include <string.h>` and with mine don´t.

Comment: I already told you. The string functions are part of the standard libraries which are always linked. It's got nothing to do with the `#include`. That doesn't tell the compiler where to look for the libs. So using anything in the standard libs does not require extra libs to be specified. Anything non-standard needs to be told to the linker.

Comment: Note that in general, you should list libraries after object files in the linking command line.  On many systems, typing `gcc ownlib.a main.c -o prog.out` will not find the symbols defined in `ownlib.a` because when the library is scanned, the only undefined symbol that the linker is looking for is `main`, and the library doesn't define `main`.  Some systems will effectively do the reordering for you, but it is not something to rely upon — what works today may not work after an upgrade.

Comment: The standard naming convention for (static) libraries is `libown.a`, in part because that allows you to specify `-L /where/it/is/installed -lown` rather specifying the archive pathname in full.  For a single library, there isn't much saving, but if there are multiple libraries, it becomes beneficial.  Additionally, if you install your library as `/usr/local/lib/libown.a`, there's a good chance that the linker will look in `/usr/local/lib` automatically and all you need on the command line is `-lown` (after the object files that you're linking).

Comment: Thaks so much @Jonathan Leffler, you has showed me the path to the light. I really apreciate the time spent with me.